# NSArray life cycle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I create an NSArray object in .h file:

```
NSArray *tempArray;
```

and than  I alloc it in .m file in viewDidLoad() method:

```
tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; //initilaize
tempArray = [connect connectSeriesJSonBack]; //fill it (I try it works)
```

But I want to use this array in another method like:

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
```

How can i organize array lifecycle because I use alloc, retain etc. no way the reach array data again.

Comment: another method in the same class... ?

Comment: yes mihir same class, I don't understand why I can't reach array's data?

Comment: if you have created tempArray in the .h file... then you should directly access the tempArray across that class... no need to do anything.... unless you are releasing it before accessing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second assignment for tempArray will generate a memory leak because the allocation can never be accessed again. `connectSeriesJSonBAck` will probably return a autoreleased `NSArray`. If you want to keep referencing it outside of the current scope then you should retain it:

instead of:

```
tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; //initilaize
tempArray = [connect connectSeriesJSonBack]; //fill it (I try it works)
```

do

```
tempArray = [connect connectSeriesJSonBack];
[tempArray retain];
```

and add `[tempArray release]` in your class' `dealloc` method.

Comment: Thank you Diederik, It works I should read a Memory Management tutorials. But Can you tell shortly? Why I must not alloc, init this object and retain it?

Comment: You asked Diederik, but probably i could give you the answer, it is because what you get from [connect connectSeriesJSonBack]; is an alloced nsarray.you just have to retain it.

Comment: [connect connectSeriesJSonBack] has no idea what you are assigning it to -- doing [[NSArray alloc] init] creates a totally new object, and then [connect connectSeriesJSonBack] does the same thing -- wasting one object.  For you other question, read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB

Answer (score 3):

Don't release the array in the method, and instead release it in the dealloc method -- that way you can use it other places.

Otherwise there is another problem here.

Here you create a retained, empty, *immutable* NSArray

```
tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

And now you overwrite the pointer to that retained instance, yay, you just leaked an NSArray

```
tempArray = [connect connectSeriesJSonBack];
```

And that method **should** be returning an autoreleased NSArray.  Which will be automatically released and go away once you hit an event loop.

You should do something like this

```
-(void)whereverThisIs {
    // Do not retain here if connectSeriesJSonBack returns a retained instance
    tempArray = [[connect connectSeriesJSonBack] retain];
 }

 -(void)dealloc {
     [tempArray release];
 }

 -(void)anotherMethod {
     if ( tempArray ) { // Do things }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the same array within the class then you can probably try making it a class variable so that its members can be accessed throughout the class.

Comment: The term is "instance variable" or "ivar"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to declar it in implemantation like

```
@implementation YourViewController

NSMutableArray *mutableExample;
// or 
NSArray *example;
```

then in `-()viewdidload` alloc it like `mutableExample = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]retain];`
or just `example = [[NSArray alloc] init];`

and the you can use it every where.do not forget to release it!!!

hope it helps if something is unclear ask it in the comment

wblade

Answer (score 0):

If you return an autoreleased array from the function `[connect connectSeriesJSonBack];` than your `tempArray` will be have a return count of 0 after the `viewDidLoad` method.

There are 2 approaches how to make it work

1) use an `NSMutableArray` object and add the objects

```
tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[connect connectSeriesJSonBack]];
```

2) retain the returned array

```
tempArray = [[connect connectSeriesJSonBack] retain];
```